# PDFBox: do PDDocument and PDPage have references to one another?

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

Does a PDPage object contains a reference to the PDDocument to which it belongs? 
In other words, does a PDPage has knowledge of its PDDocument?
Somewhere in the application I have a list of PDDocuments.
These documents get merged into one new PDDocument:

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();

PDDocument mergedPDDocument = new PDDocument();
for (PDDocument pdfDocument : documentList) {
    pdfMerger.appendDocument(mergedPDDocument, pdfDocument);
}
```

Then this PdDocument gets split into bundles of 10:

```
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
splitter.setSplitAtPage(bundleSize);
List<PDDocument> bundleList = splitter.split(mergedDocument);
```

My question with this is now:
if I loop over the pages of these splitted PDDocuments in the list, is there a way to know to which PDDocument a page originally belonged?

Also, if you have a PDPage object, can you get information from it like, it's pagenumber, ....?
Or can you get this via another way?

Comment: second part of your question: `doc.getPages().indexOf(page)`. Re first part - what is the context of your question? I think it is "no" but I just woke up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does a `PDPage` object contains a reference to the `PDDocument` to which it belongs? In other words, does a `PDPage` has knowledge of its `PDDocument`?

> Unfortunately the `PDPage` does not contain a reference to its parent `PDDocument`, but it has a list of all other pages in the document that can be used to navigate between pages without a reference to the parent `PDDocument`.

2. If you have a `PDPage` object, can you get information from it like its page number, or can you get this via another way?

> There is a workaround to get information about the position of a `PDPage` in the document without the `PDDocument` available.  Each `PDPage` has a **dictionary** with information about the size of the page, resources, fonts, content, etc.  One of these attributes is called **Parent**, this is an array of **Pages** that have all the information needed to create a shallow clone of the `PDPage` using the constructor `PDPage(COSDictionary)`. The pages are in the correct order so the page number can be obtain by the position of the record in the array.

3. If I loop over the pages of these splitted `PDDocuments` in the list, is there a way to know to which `PDDocument` a page originally belonged?

> Once you merge the document list into a single document all references to the original documents will be lost. You can confirm this by looking at the **Parent** object inside the `PDPage`, go to *Parent > Kids > COSObject[n] > Parent* and see if the number for Parent is the same for all the elements in the array. In this example Parent is `COSName {Parent} : 1781256139;` for all pages.

```
COSName {Parent} : COSObject {
  COSDictionary {
    COSName {Kids} : COSArray {
      COSObject {
        COSDictionary {
          COSName {TrimBox} : COSArray {0; 0; 612; 792;};
          COSName {MediaBox} : COSArray {0; 0; 612; 792;};
          COSName {CropBox} : COSArray {0; 0; 612; 792;};
          COSName {Resources} : COSDictionary {
            ...
          };
          COSName {Contents} : COSObject {
            ...
          };
          COSName {Parent} : 1781256139;
          COSName {StructParents} : COSInt {68};
          COSName {ArtBox} : COSArray {0; 0; 612; 792; };
          COSName {BleedBox} : COSArray {0; 0; 612; 792; };
          COSName {Type} : COSName {Page};
        }
    }

    ...

    COSName {Count} : COSInt {4};
    COSName {Type} : COSName {Pages};
  }
};
```

---

**Source code**

I wrote the following code to show how the information from the `PDPage` dictionary can be used to navigate the pages back and forward and get the page number using the position in the array.

```
public class PDPageUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            String filename = "src/main/resources/pdf/us-017.pdf";
            document = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));

            System.out.println("listIterator(PDPage)");
            ListIterator<PDPage> pageIterator = listIterator(document.getPage(0));
            while (pageIterator.hasNext()) {
                PDPage page = pageIterator.next();
                System.out.println("page #: " + pageIterator.nextIndex() + ", Structural Parent Key: " + page.getStructParents());
            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a <code>ListIterator</code> initialized with the list of pages from
     * the dictionary embedded in the specified <code>PDPage</code>. The current
     * position of this <code>ListIterator</code> is set to the position of the
     * specified <code>PDPage</code>.
     * 
     * @param page the specified <code>PDPage</code>
     * 
     * @see {@link java.util.ListIterator}
     * @see {@link org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage}
     */
    public static ListIterator<PDPage> listIterator(PDPage page) {
        List<PDPage> pages = new LinkedList<PDPage>();

        COSDictionary pageDictionary = page.getCOSObject();
        COSDictionary parentDictionary = pageDictionary.getCOSDictionary(COSName.PARENT);
        COSArray kidsArray = parentDictionary.getCOSArray(COSName.KIDS);

        List<? extends COSBase> kidList = kidsArray.toList();
        for (COSBase kid : kidList) {
            if (kid instanceof COSObject) {
                COSObject kidObject = (COSObject) kid;
                COSBase type = kidObject.getDictionaryObject(COSName.TYPE);
                if (type == COSName.PAGE) {
                    COSBase kidPageBase = kidObject.getObject();
                    if (kidPageBase instanceof COSDictionary) {
                        COSDictionary kidPageDictionary = (COSDictionary) kidPageBase;
                        pages.add(new PDPage(kidPageDictionary));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int index = pages.indexOf(page);
        return pages.listIterator(index);
    }
}
```

---

**Sample output**

In this example the PDF document has 4 pages and the iterator was initialized with the first page. Notice that the page number is the `previousIndex()`

```
System.out.println("listIterator(PDPage)");
ListIterator<PDPage> pageIterator = listIterator(document.getPage(0));
while (pageIterator.hasNext()) {
    PDPage page = pageIterator.next();
    System.out.println("page #: " + pageIterator.previousIndex() + ", Structural Parent Key: " + page.getStructParents());
}
```

```
listIterator(PDPage)
page #: 0, Structural Parent Key: 68
page #: 1, Structural Parent Key: 69
page #: 2, Structural Parent Key: 70
page #: 3, Structural Parent Key: 71
```

You can also navigate backwards by starting from the last page. Notice now that the page number is the `nextIndex()`.

```
ListIterator<PDPage> pageIterator = listIterator(document.getPage(3));
pageIterator.next();
while (pageIterator.hasPrevious()) {
    PDPage page = pageIterator.previous();
    System.out.println("page #: " + pageIterator.nextIndex() + ", Structural Parent Key: " + page.getStructParents());
}
```

```
listIterator(PDPage)
page #: 3, Structural Parent Key: 71
page #: 2, Structural Parent Key: 70
page #: 1, Structural Parent Key: 69
page #: 0, Structural Parent Key: 68
```

Comment: `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");` is no longer needed if you're using the latest jdk8. The warning no longer comes in 2.0.13 when using jdk8.